# Extract value from loc output in bash

Tags: bash

Using [loc](https://github.com/cgag/loc) I am able to get statistics about the number of lines in the cwd:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Language             Files        Lines        Blank      Comment         Code
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TypeScript             108        18640         2049         1717        14874
 JSON                     3        13293            0            0        13293
 Markdown                 8          725          183            0          542
 HTML                     1           14            3            0           11
 JavaScript               2           12            1            3            8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total                  122        32684         2236         1720        28728
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a bash script to get the count of the TypeScript code in the project (*14874* in this example). The regexp `TypeScript.*?(\d+)$` matches the value I want but I am having difficulties using it.

I have tried two methods so far:

- grep: Can get the whole matched line **BUT** cannot get the digit group
- bash's `=~`: Can get groups **BUT** cannot use `$` to match the end of the line

What is best way to extract this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use awk to find the `TypeScript` line and print the 6th column:

```
loc ... | awk '$1=="TypeScript" {print $6}'
```

Answer (score 1):

> get the count of the TypeScript code
> [...]
> The regexp `TypeScript.*?(\d+)$` matches the value I want

`sed` can extract groups from regexes using `\1`, `\2`, … in `s/regex/replacement/`. However, `sed` (just like posix `grep` and bash's `[[ =~ ]]`) do not support PCRE constructs like `\d` and `.*?`. But we actually don't need them here.

You might want to let `loc` count only TypeScript files to safe lots of unnecessary work.

```
loc --include '\.ts$' | sed -n 's/^ *TypeScript.* //p'
```

Due to the `include` you could even simplify the parsing to one of the following commands (even though they are a bit more cryptic):

- `grep -Em1 '[0-9]+$'`
- `sed -n '4s/.* //p'`
- `awk 'NR==4 {print $(NF-1)}'`